# What are the alternatives to Quickbooks?

Tags: software-rec, quickbooks

Quickbooks is very complex and not very user friendly, especially for a small business owner. Are there any other online accountancy programs that would also take care of creating tax papers to be sent out?

Comment: This site will show you some up to date options. http://alternativeto.net/software/quickbooks/?exactmatch=true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Freshbooks](http://freshbooks.com) is very nice, but doesn't do everything quickbooks does (but see [this blog post about Bootstrap](http://www.freshbooks.com/blog/2008/10/03/bootstrap-brings-quarterly-tax-estimates-to-freshbooks/) for quartely tax estimates and [this forum post re:limitations](http://community.freshbooks.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=3650).

[Cashboard](http://www.getcashboard.com/) is another online billing application. However I don't see any tax integration.

Though not online, there is also [GnuCash](http://www.gnucash.org/) which is about as user friendly as Quickbooks (not very). I know some people use both Freshbooks and GnuCash. And [Postbooks](http://sourceforge.net/projects/postbooks/) which is another open-sauce billing app.